# How to get a CSS property of an HTML element from its class?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using javascript to get the src element of an `img` with this script:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
            var src = evt.target.src 
}
```

but some images don't have `src` attribute as it is set in the `currentSrc` property of its css class like this one:

```
<img alt="Chaussure de football enfant terrain sec Agility 900 FG bleu rouge" class="source-medium">
```

and the source-medium css class contains:

```
currentSrc: "https://contents.mediadecathlon.com/p1353468/k$6b31ed91fa5b73e99f89ff262c0985c7/s
```

My question is how to get the `currentSrc` property with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `evt.target.currentSrc`?

If you only want the sources from the `img` elements with the source-medium class you can select those elements and get their source: `document.querySelectorAll('.source-medium')` and then loop over the result with a for loop or something.